# Let a function take precedence/priority over another in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongodb-query, synchronous

I have a MongoClient function which seems to be asynchronous in nature. Followed by child process function which I am explicitly declaring as synchronous. The cp takes a parameter `nextPort`, and the value of `nextPort` is assigned inside `MongoClient`. Since `cp.execSync` takes precedence over `MongoClient` it doesn't take the new value of the variable rather the value it was declared with.

*app.js*

```
var nextPort=0; //Declaration 
MongoClient.connect(url1,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    dbo.collection("mycol").distinct('port', function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      portArr=result;
      console.log(portArr.length);
      nextPort = portArr[portArr.length-1]+1; //New Value of nextPort
      console.log(nextPort);
      db.close();
    });
});

console.log('Container Created\n');
console.log(nextPort);
const result3 = cp.execSync('docker run -d -p '+nextPort+':27017 -v '+volumeLoc+' --name '+containerName+' mongo:'+version); 
//Taking the declaration value instead of new
console.log(result3.toString());
```

How do I execute `MongoClient` before `cp.execSync`. (Also, I'd really appreciate if the solution doesn't deal with promises)

Comment: Asking for a solution that doesn't involve promises is like asking to pound a nail in without a hammer when it's the best tool for the job.  Promises are the best tool the Javascript language has for sequencing asynchronous operations and the sooner you learn how to use them with your database, the faster you can write good, clear and solid code for problems like this.

Comment: `cp.execSync` doesn't really take precedence, it's just running before the `connect` and `distinct` async functions have completed. If you don't want promises, the `cp.execSync` needs to be nested within the async functions (around the `console.log(nextPort)`)

Answer (score 1):

Try to learn the `async / await` syntax for cleaner code. I dont know if this is just a script or an function, anyway, i wrapped it in an async IIFE:

```
(async () => {
  var nextPort = 0; //Declaration
  try {
    var db = await MongoClient.connect(url1, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

    var dbo = db.db("mydb");

    var result = await dbo.collection("mycol").distinct("port");
    portArr = result;
    console.log(portArr.length);
    nextPort = portArr[portArr.length - 1] + 1; //New Value of nextPort
    console.log(nextPort);
    db.close();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  console.log("Container Created\n");
  console.log(nextPort);
  const result3 = cp.execSync(
    "docker run -d -p " +
      nextPort +
      ":27017 -v " +
      volumeLoc +
      " --name " +
      containerName +
      " mongo:" +
      version
  );
  //Taking the declaration value instead of new
  console.log(result3.toString());
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to call your `cp.execSync` inside the callback function you provided to `MongoClient.connect` or you should use `async/await` syntax, e.g.:

```
const client = await MongoClient.connect(url1, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
const result3 = cp.execSync(...)
```

Make sure your wrapper function (factory method to instantiate a client in 
a separate module would be better approach) is `async`, take a look at the [example](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/reference/ecmascriptnext/connecting/)